# I want to do an addressage automatic with my dhcp server

Tags: 12.04, server, dhcp

```
nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
   authoritative;
   ddns-update-style none;
   default-lease-time 240;
   max-lease-time 380;
   subnet 192.168.21.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   range 192.168.21.30 192.168.21.70
   option routers 192.168.21.1}
flore{
hardware ethernet 08:00:27:e1:f0:4e;
fixed address 192.168.21.40;
}
```

When I write `service isc-dhcp-server restart` in */etc/init.d*, I have this error:

```
start: job failed to start
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolons in your subnet declaration, and the term `host` from your host declaration, the following should get you on track:

```
authoritative;
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 240;
max-lease-time 380;
subnet 192.168.21.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.21.30 192.168.21.70;
  option routers 192.168.21.1;
}

host flore {
  hardware ethernet 08:00:27:e1:f0:4e;
  fixed address 192.168.21.40;
}
```